# c# how to get list of derived class properties by reflection, ordered by base class properties first, and then derived class props

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, properties, derived-class

i am looking to get a list of properties from a derived class 
i wrote a function that gives my a list of properties.
my problem is that i want the list of properties to contain first properties of base class and after properties of derived class
how can i do this? now i get first properties in derived and then of base

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        Dictionary<string, ColumnInfo> _colsDict = new Dictionary<string, ColumnInfo>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (object attr in attrs)
            {
                ColumnInfo colInfoAttr = attr as ColumnInfo;
                if (colInfoAttr != null)
                {
                    string propName = prop.Name;
                    _colsDict.Add(propName, colInfoAttr);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm... I think you need to extract the base class first, get it properties and add the remaining. Be aware; properties can be "newed", and the base class can have a base class.

Comment: how can i extract remaining fields of derived class after extracting fields of base class?

Comment: there is `Reverse()` method

Comment: but that will revert all my properties, i don't wan't that
i want base class to appear first in its order and then derived fields in their order

Comment: I might be missing the whole point. Can't you use Type.BaseType to get the base class and get the properties from it if BaseType exists?

Comment: @zipo13 - i can do this to get the base class properties,
but i want to have also derived class properties to appear after base properties

Comment: I see there is already an answer by Shoejep. I thought to first get the properties of the base class. Then get all the properties and remove those that already found in the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the base class type, you can probably do something like this:

```
  public static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties<Derived, Base>()
  {
        var onlyInterestedInTypes = new[] { typeof(Derived).Name, typeof(Base).Name };

        return Assembly
            .GetAssembly(typeof(Derived))
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => onlyInterestedInTypes.Contains(x.Name))
            .OrderBy(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)))
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties())
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (object)x.Name);
  }
```

The important part for you being `.OrderBy(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)))` which will order the properties.

Comment: i used the above reply, but i get a dictionary with lot of data including not just properties @Shoejep can you please help?
my code is :
            List<PropertyInfo> props = Assembly
            .GetAssembly(typeof(T))
            .GetTypes()
            .OrderBy(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseAuctionDataSum)))
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties())
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x=>x.First())
            .ToList();
why do i get more records than i expect?

Comment: I've created a .Net fiddle of how you should use my answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vqzR3k, as I don't know what type "T" or "BaseAuctionDataSum" is, in your comment.

Comment: i tried this again, but had the same problem, as you can see in my fiddle attached https://dotnetfiddle.net/zuRNaz , if there are any more classes in the assembly i get their properties too, but i want only the properties of my base and derived class

Comment: Oops, my bad, I've added another fiddle where it only picks out the base and derived types: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jVTBYP