# How do I get the base class properties to populate before the derived class properties in ASP.NET MVC 5.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty sure I've seen this answered before but I cannot remember how I asked the question of Google. When ASP.NET MVC posts and populates a model (Viewmodel) it matches based on the name. In this case I have a base class with some shared properties (see below) and another derived that adds a few more plus some methods. When the post occurs, the derived class has a dependency on the properties in the base class to call the data layer (Prop4) but these properties(Prop1 and Prop2) are not yet populated. How do I switch the order or at least ensure that these base class properties are populated first?

```
public class BaseClass
{ 
     public string Prop1{get;set;} 
     public string Prop2{get;set;}
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{
     private IList<datamodel> _data = null;
     public string Prop3 {get;set}
     public IList<datamodel> Prop4
     {
          get
          {
               if(this._data is null)
               {
                  // this line on Post will have Prop1 and Prop2 as defaults - not what is posted
                  this._data = getdata(this.Prop1, this.Prop2); 
               }
               return this._data
           }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# how to get list of derived class properties by reflection, ordered by base class properties first, and then derived class props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645680/c-sharp-how-to-get-list-of-derived-class-properties-by-reflection-ordered-by-ba)

Comment: On first look, I think it informs it but not quite there. But I am still looking at it to see if I can take it and place it into some ActionFilter Attribute or something. Thanks!